# 'View in browser' link on mailing gives 'Access denied' error

Tags: civimail, permissions

If I click on the 'view in browser' link on a mailing sent via CiviMail I get to a page on the website that says 'Access denied'.

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the permissions to allow the public to view the mailing.

This permission is called: 'CiviMail: view public CiviMail content'.  This should be assigned to the anonymous role (or all user roles).

You also need to ensure that the mailing visibility is set to 'Public pages' for each mailing that you want to be available to view.  This setting is found under 'Publication'.

Comment: What if your mailing is set to publish on public pages, AND you've given the 'CiviMail: view public CiviMail content' permission to Anonymous (and registered) users?  I'm still getting a 403 response from my webserver.

e.g. "GET /civicrm/mailing/view?id=34 HTTP/1.1" 403 15857 

https://equality-tech.com/civicrm/mailing/view?id=34

Comment: Hi Greg, you are more likely to get a response if you post this as a new question.

Comment: In my case, it turns out that I could only view the message after it was sent. The assigned ID of the public message is a lot different from the draft id. In other words, instead of being id=34 it was https://equality-tech.com/civicrm/mailing/view?reset=1&id=1331cff42bfc5ab5

Comment: Glad that you managed to resolve this.